# winJS(CameraCaptureUI) How to preview(done) and SAVE(?) picture to disk?

Tags: camera, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, winjs

I researched a lot and tried a bunch of things that don't work. 
So what I need is:

1. get picture (working)
2. display as preview for user (working)
3. creating an image in picture library (working)
4. save the preview as that image to local picture folder (missing)

Thanks.

I capture a picture and display it on page like this:

```
  function captureImage()

{

 //S1: Create a new Camera Capture UI Object

 var cam = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();

 var name = document.getElementById('ticketnum').innerHTML+'.jpg';

 var folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary; //was windows.storage

 //S2: Perform an Async operation where the Capture

 // Image will be stored as file

cam.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo)

 .done(function (data) {

 if (data)

 {

 //S3: Create a URL for the capture image

 // and assign it to the <Img>

 var urlpic= window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

document.getElementById('imgCapture').src

 = urlpic;

 //**save picture to memory as ticket number, creating new img, how to put the file inside?

folder.createFileAsync(name, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting) //creates new file?

 .then(function (file) {

//file.copyAndReplaceAsync(window.URL.createObjectURL(data));
// HOW TO SAVE IMAGE TO pictures library? 
 });


    }

 }

 , error);

document.getElementById('txtserver').value = "Done";

 //save image to memory?

 //clean up resources

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
function testSavePictureDisk() {    
    // S1: Create a new Camera Capture UI Object
    var cam = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI();

    //location?
    var name = document.getElementById('ticketnum').innerHTML + '.jpg';

    var folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary; //was windows.storage

    // S2: Perform an Async operation where the Capture
    // Image will be stored as file
    folder.createFileAsync(name, 
        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting) //creates new file?
        .then(function (file) {
            cam.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo)
               .done(function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        //S3: Create a URL for the capture image
                        // and assign it to the <Img>
                        document.getElementById('imgCapture').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

                        //**save picture to memory as ticket number
                        data.moveAndReplaceAsync(file);

                        //**end testing for local save
                    }
                }
            , error);

        document.getElementById('txtserver').value = "Done";

        //save image to memory?
        //clean up resources
    });//end of new file creation
}
```

### Steps

1. Create new file
2. Capture a picture and preview it
3. Move picture to file

Comment: Yes, you found that the "data" variable you're getting back from the capture is a StorageFile object, and if you look at its properties you'll see that camera capture creates a file in your temp appdata location. So you can use its moveAsync or moveAndReplaceAsync methods to transfer it to another location.